# How to check if Javascript is activated from Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, gecko

I haven't found any info on that. I basically need to know from a Firefox extension if the browser has javascript enabled. Is that possible?

I am totally new to programming FF extensions -- actually this is my first one and among the requirements is this one I haven't been able to figure out.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. 80% of valuable audience will have JS enabled. Why twist and turn about the other 20%? Just assume they support it. Of course it depends on your deployment domain, but if it is anything like normal, 80%.

Comment: Thanks Cris, Yeah I agree. But I really need to know for sure. I haven't found a way to detected it.

Comment: Good question. I just googled it and could not find anything. But I'm sure someone who develops FF ext must know. You might want to add where you have looked for info, a bit more about why you need JS, and which FF versions you are targeting.

Comment: There are way to detect JavaScript being properly disabled (e.g. by checking `javascript.enabled` preference) but detecting NoScript and the like will be hard because it uses [security policies](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html) to disable JavaScript selectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [@ChristianSonne](https://twitter.com/#!/ChristianSonne/status/177023360931340289): You could try

```
require("preferences-service").get("javascript.enabled")
```

in Jetpack-style addons.